# php bootstrap modal pass id user

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

how to open a modal with id from this code

```
<a href = "../user/scalauser.php?id_user='. $row['id_user']. '" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Scale Points</a>
```

example modal

'''

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

'''

Comment: Your link doesn't make a lot of sense. Either you want it to redirect to the scaluser.php page, or you want it to open a modal on the current page.

Comment: As for the id, it will open the modal which has the id `myModal` in its HTML - as per `data-target="#myModal"`. The HTML you've shown doesn't contain that, but I assume you've just not shown us some of the outer HTML. Or are you talking about the `user_id`? it really wasn't clear at all what your intention is. You need to clarify the question significantly. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but I was wrong, the modal exists and it is in another page called scalauser.php and I would like to open it as modal

Comment: If the modal is in another page you have to let the user navigate to that page, and then when that page has loaded, that's the time you can open the modal. You can't open it beforehand, because it doesn't exist yet. All you could potentially do is send something to that page to indicate that it should arrange for the modal to be opened immediately - e.g. in your case you're setting the `id_user` parameter in the URL, so you could use that as the trigger.

Comment: if I insert the modal on the same page?

Comment: Then you can load it easily yes, and you wouldn't need the href in the link. If you then needed to fetch extra data with which to populate the modal, consider using AJAX

Comment: would you be kind enough to show me an example with my code?

Comment: example of what exactly? I see you accepted the answer below already, so presumably your question is solved now?

Comment: I added the select to read the information based on id_user but the fields are empty

Comment: That's too vague for anyone to usefully help you with. I suggest opening a new question about this specific issue, since you've accepted the answer to your original query. Then you can provide sufficient details about what you've done and where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the modal on the current page, you can do something like this:

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-<?php echo $row['id_user']; ?>">Open modal</a>
```

and the modal should look like this:

```html
<div class="modal-content" id="modal-<?php echo $row['id_user']; ?>">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the official bootstrap modal example:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal-<?php echo $row['id_user']; ?>">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal-<?php echo $row['id_user']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel-<?php echo $row['id_user']; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel-<?php echo $row['id_user']; ?>">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if I enter this code, the modal is immediately opened without pressing the key

Comment: Updated my answer with the official bootstrap modal example. It should not open anything without pressing the button.

Comment: I added the select to read the information based on id_user but the fields are empty